# Problem installing node packages, node-gyp rebuild

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-gyp

I'm sort of a beginner in node, but I've been working on a discord bot with discord.js for a while. I wanted to host it on an EC2 server on AWS. However, when I try `sudo npm install` to install the packages, I get this:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-33-102:~$ sudo npm install

> ref@1.3.5 install /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ref
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ref/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ref
gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> node-opus@0.3.1 install /home/ubuntu/node_modules/node-opus
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/node_modules/node-opus/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/node_modules/node-opus
gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enmap@4.5.0 requires a peer of better-sqlite-pool@github:eslachance/better-sqlite-pool but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref@1.3.5 (node_modules/ref):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref@1.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-opus@0.3.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-opus@0.3.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2019-01-06T07_12_30_305Z-debug.log
```

The log mentioned in the last line is [here](https://gist.github.com/piguyisme/28f83eed587b1262fa9083b2ad2bcbf8).

I have looked around and while people have similar problems, none of the fixes work.

The full code for the bot is [here](https://github.com/piguyisme/TazeBot) if you need it.
I just need to know how to resolve this error so the packages can install.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If someone find this question via google (like me) here an answer:
In my case it was a missing "g++" lib.

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

did the trick for me.